# typescript warning Missing return type on function

Tags: typescript

I am using typrscript.
Missing return type on function.eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types) at (d:number).
How can I get rid of the warning?

```
const createDateTime = (d: number) => {
  const datetime = new Date(d * 1000);
  return datetime.toLocaleDateString();
};
```

Comment: Did you try to add return type to the functiion?
```const createDateTime = (d: number): string => {...} ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define a return type to your function:

```
const createDateTime = (d: number): string => {
  const datetime = new Date(d * 1000);
  return datetime.toLocaleDateString();
};
```

Comment: what if it doesnt return something?

Comment: @jenuel ganawed so you can use `void`